# Efficient Algorithm Required For Range Queries

Tags: c++, algorithm

I want to know the best way to implement this (approach). I will bee given set of coordinates (x,y). I will then be queried based on those coordinates like 

1.C a b => where a and b are integer indexes in the initial set of coordinates. So I need to output the number of points that are in 1st ,2nd ,3rd and fourth quadrant that are in index range a to b.

2.X a b => where a and b are integer indexes in the initial set of coordinates. So I need to mirror the ath to bth indexed coordinates along x axis.

3.Y a b => where a and b are integer indexes in the initial set of coordinates. So I need to mirror the ath to bth indexed coordinates along y axis.

there can be at most 100000 coordinates or points and 500000 such queries on them.

I tried a brute force method looping through on every query but it had TLE(Time Limit Exceeded).

What should I do in such type of questions?

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

char flipX[4] = { 3, 2, 1, 0 };
char flipY[4] = { 1, 0, 3, 2 };

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int n,x,y;
    char c[100000];
    scanf("%d",&n);
    //coord *c=new coord[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&x);
        scanf("%d",&y);
        if(x<0 && y<0)
            c[i]=2;
        else if(x>0 && y>0)
            c[i]=0;
        else if(x>0 && y<0)
            c[i]=3;
        else
            c[i]=1;
    }

    int q,i,j,a,cnt[4];
    char ch;
    scanf("%d",&q);
    while(q--)
    {
        //cout<<"q:"<<q<<endl;
        cin>>ch;
        scanf("%d",&i);
        scanf("%d",&j);
        i--;j--;
        if(ch=='X')
        {
            //case 'X':
                for(a=i;a<=j;a++)
                    c[a]=flipX[c[a]];
            //  break;
        }
        else if(ch=='Y')
        {
            //case 'Y':
                for(a=i;a<=j;a++)
                    c[a]=flipY[c[a]];
            //  break;
        }   
        else if(ch=='C')
        {
                cnt[0]=cnt[1]=cnt[2]=cnt[3]=0;
                for(a=i;a<=j;a++)
                {
                    cnt[c[a]]++;
                }
                printf("%d %d %d %d\n",cnt[0],cnt[1],cnt[2],cnt[3]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please Help.

Comment: Homework or programming contest?

Comment: Wait, are the coordinate values even relevant? Looks like all you care about is the quadrant they are in...

Comment: contest. here .. https://www.interviewstreet.com/challenges/dashboard/#problem/4e48b9cb8917f . And yes only quadrants are important

Comment: Also I thought of segment trees. They only pass 3 test cases while the brute force passed 8 test cases. I am stumped..  @nneonneo

Comment: Why don't you post your code?

Comment: @paddy: code posted. Please see if something can be improved on

Comment: I would say for starters that you are not reading the input properly.  You are supposed to read a line and then process that.  You are assuming that next time you read a character it will be a command, and you can immediately read two integers.  You did not check that read was successful and/or did not initialise the values before reading.  It's possible they've given you bad input to run you overtime.  If fixing your input doesn't help, you'll need to be much more clever.  I think the idea of segment trees sounds good, if you have a tree for each quadrant and your values are indices.

Comment: @paddy: I just edited with the latest lazy segment tree code I have. Still no luck. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Lazy segment trees did the trick. Thanx everyone for your help

Answer (score 1):

Agree with nneonneo.

```
const size_t MAX_COORDS = 100000;
vector<char> quadrant( MAX_COORDS );
```

Here, `quadrant` maintains a value (0 to 3).  It's pretty trivial to flip quadrants without any conditionals:

```
char flipX[4] = { 2, 3, 0, 1 };
char flipY[4] = { 3, 2, 1, 0 };

vector<char>::iterator itLeft = quadrant.begin() + left;
vector<char>::iterator itRight = quadrant.begin() + right + 1;

for( vector<char>::iterator it = itLeft; it != itRight; it++ )
{
    *it = flipX[*it];
}
```

And it's equally easy to count quadrants:

```
unsigned int count[4] = {0};
for( vector<char>::iterator it = itLeft; it != itRight; it++ )
{
    count[*it]++;
}
```

If you need to be faster than that, you'll have to take a dynamic programming approach and memoize the quadrant count for every point and every quadrant.  That will give you O(1) range searches but will make the mirroring operations considerably more expensive.  Here is how the range count would work:

```
vector< vector<char> > counts( 4, vector<char>(MAX_COORDS) );

// ...

for( size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
    count[i] = counts[i][right] - (left > 0 ? counts[i][left-1] : 0);
}
```

Comment: I like how you flipped the quadrant via an array and not with if condition. That is cool.... @paddy

Comment: I'll try that and get back to you

Comment: I juz tried the above approach. It cleared another test case. i.e. 9/11. Still not through with this approach. Also I think the dynamic programming approach mentioned above is too slow.

Comment: Which test cases remain?  Are you including the edges of the range?  It's quite common to make the mistake of loop-testing with `<` instead of `<=`.  Did you still exceed the time limit?